# Need to simplify an update query in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help in simplifying the following update query if it is possible, it seems like extra unnecessary selects are included:

```
UPDATE TARGET a
SET a.ACCOUNTID = (SELECT x.SFDC_ID
                     FROM   SOURCE x
                   WHERE  a.ACCOUNTID = x.LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C
                      AND x.SFDC_ID is not null) 
WHERE  a.ACCOUNTID = (SELECT LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C
                       FROM   SOURCE x
                      WHERE  a.ACCOUNTID = x.LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C
                         AND x.SFDC_ID is not null)
```

Comment: First Step to simplify, format it!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT a.ACCOUNTID , x.SFDC_ID
FROM TARGET a
INNER JOIN SOURCE x 
ON a.ACCOUNTID = x.LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C
  AND x.SFDC_ID is not null
) t
SET t.ACCOUNTID = t.SFDC_ID
```

Comment: I know I asked for a simpler method, but will this method also be more efficient/better/faster? Please explain if so.

Comment: Too many variables to know (indexes/partitions/etc).  You'd have to run it both ways and compare.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this using "exists" condition.

```
 UPDATE TARGET a
    SET a.ACCOUNTID = (SELECT x.SFDC_ID
                         FROM   SOURCE x
                       WHERE  a.ACCOUNTID = x.LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C
                          AND x.SFDC_ID is not null) 
    WHERE  exists (SELECT 1
                           FROM   SOURCE x
                          WHERE  a.ACCOUNTID = x.LEGACY_SYSTEM_ID__C
                             AND x.SFDC_ID is not null)
```

Comment: What's the advantage here?